# Есть ли разница между "Зачем он это сделал?" и "Зачем он сделал это?"

Tags: орфоэпия, семантика

Зашла на другой сайт "Русский язык". Там обсуждался такой вопрос: Есть ли смысловая разница между "Зачем он это сделал?" и "Зачем он сделал это?"

[https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/18121/Разница-между-Зачем-он-это-сделал-и-Зачем-он-сделал-это](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/18121/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%B8-%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE)

Ответ, получивший 12 голосов, меня несколько удивил:

> В русском языке слово, на которое приходится смысловое/логическое ударение, как правило переносится в конец фразы. Таким образом
>
> Вопрос 1 ставится к сказуемому - зачем сделал.
>
> Вопрос 2 ставится к дополнению - зачем сделал именно это, а не что-то другое.

(Орфография и пунктуация — авторские.)

**А как бы вы ответили на него?**

Answer (score 1):

Естественно, нормальный порядок слов - в первом варианте. Второй - просто инверсия. Смысловой разницы никакой.

Comment: Спасибо. А что Вы можете сказать про  всеми одобренный ответ, связанный с логическим ударением?

Comment: Это, мягко говоря, чушь. Вы меня провоцируете? Да, я привык называть кошку кошкой.